# Forms open for every item in a list when I want to only open a form for that specific item in a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-redux

What the code looks like rendering the button to show the form

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { deleteSong, getSongs, updateSong } from '../../store/song';

import ReactAudioPlayer from 'react-audio-player';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
import SongForm from '../AddSongForm';
import EditSongForm from '../EditSongForm';


const SongList = () => {

    const [addShowForm, setAddShowForm] = useState(false);
    const [editShowForm, setEditShowForm] = useState(false);

    const history = useHistory()
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const songsObj = useSelector((state) => state.songState.entries);
    const songs = Object.values(songsObj)

    const user = useSelector((state) => state.session.user);
    const CurrentUserId = user?.id

    const remove = (e) => {
        dispatch(deleteSong(e.target.id));
    }

    const addFormCheck = (e) => {
        if (addShowForm) setAddShowForm(false)
        if (!addShowForm) setAddShowForm(true)
    }
    const editFormCheck = (e) => {
        if (editShowForm) setEditShowForm(false)
        if (!editShowForm) setEditShowForm(true)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getSongs());
    }, [dispatch]);


    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={addFormCheck}>add a song</button>
                {addShowForm ?
                    <SongForm />
                    : null}
            </div>
            <h1>Song List</h1>
            <ol>
                {songs.map(({ id, songName, songLink, userId }) => (
                    <div className='songdetails' key={id}>
                        <p key={id}>songName={songName}</p>
                        <ReactAudioPlayer
                            src={songLink}
                            autoPlay
                            controls
                            key={songLink}
                        />
                        {userId === CurrentUserId ?
                            <>
                                <div>
                                    <button id={id} onClick={remove}>remove</button>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <button id={id} onClick={editFormCheck}>edit</button>
                                    {editShowForm ?
                                        <EditSongForm props={id} />
                                        : null}
                                </div>
                            </>
                            : null}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </ol>
        </div>
    );
};
export default SongList;
```

The actual form

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import { updateSong } from "../../store/song";

import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const EditSongForm = ({ props }) => {
    console.log(props)
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const [songName, setSongName] = useState("");
    const [songLink, setSongLink] = useState("");
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);


    const reset = () => {
        setSongName("");
        setSongLink("");
        // setAlbumName('');
        // setArtistName('')
    };
    const user = useSelector((state) => state.session.user);
    const userId = user?.id

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {

        e.preventDefault();
        const updatedSongDetails = {
            id: props,
            songName,
            songLink,
            userId
        };
        let updatedSong = await dispatch(updateSong(updatedSongDetails))
            .catch(async (res) => {
                const data = await res.json()
                if (data && data.errors) setErrors(data.errors)
            })
        reset();
    };

    return (
        <div className="inputBox">
            <h1>Update A Song</h1>
            <ul>
                {errors.map((error, idx) => <li className='errors' key={idx}>{error}</li>)}
            </ul>

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={(e) => setSongName(e.target.value)}
                    value={songName}
                    placeholder="Song Name"
                    name="Song Name"
                />
                <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={(e) => setSongLink(e.target.value)}
                    value={songLink}
                    placeholder="Song Link"
                    name="Audio File"
                />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default EditSongForm;
```

Right now when I have a list of songs and click the button for the edit form to appear it applies to the entire list if I have more than one song uploaded. I'm not sure how to make it specific enough so only one form opens at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a component for specific song details and then render that in the .map.

```
  <h1>Song List</h1>
            <ol>
                {songs.map(({ id, songName, songLink, userId }) => (
                    <div>
                        <SpecificSong id={id} songName={songName} songLink={songLink} userId={userId} />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </ol>
```